# iOS : load content for UIWebView from Server

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'd like to load content (HTML / CSS, Javascript - all files packed in a zip-file) into my application folder and runs it in an UIWebView. I guess this is possible, however I'm not sure if Apple allows it. 
So Is the dynamic loading and storing of HTML pages generally allowed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Loading of web pages that way is fine as far as I know.  I am working on a project that uses this zip archive tool to unpack the zip.  It is a object oriented C wrapper on minizip

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/source/browse/trunk/ZipArchive.h